# sum number and integral sum number of graphs

Tags: graph-theory

The (integral) sum graph of a finite subset $S \subset \mathbb{N(Z)}$ is the graph (S, E) with $uv \in E$ if and only if $u + v \in S$. A graph G is said to be an (integral) sum graph if it is isomorphic to the (integral) sum graph of some $S \subset \mathbb{N(Z)}.$ The (integral) sum number of a given graph G is the smallest number of isolated nodes which when added to G result in an (integral) sum graph.
One of the theorem stated that the sum number of $C_n$ is 3 when n=4 and 2 otherwise. But when I labelled my graph $C_4$, to have sum graph, I only need 2 isolated vertices and hence, the sum number is 2. The labeling is realized by {1,2,3,4,5,7} where isolated vertices are labelled 5 and 7. Moreover, For $C_4$, the integral sum number is also 4 (since integral sum number and sum number are equal for $C_4$). But the integral sum number I obtained is 1 and the labeling is realized by {-1,0,1,2,3} where the isolated vertex is labelled 3.
Please help me, I don't know what's wrong with my labelling.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your labelings is that you have *too* many numbers that are close together in $S$. In your sum graph labeling of $C_4$ with $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ labeling the cycle cyclicly and $\{5, 7\}$ labeling the isolated vertices, since $2 + 5 = 7$, there should be an edged between $2$ and $5$, but $5$ should be isolated. A similar problem happens in your other example.

I'm curious to see a proof that this (integral) sum number always exists.